# Make try catch statement identify various errors

Tags: java, sql, exception, try-catch

Hello I am working with JAVA, making a swt app that can insert directly into a database from a text file. I am struggling with just the final parts, the error detection part of the app. I can insert just fine into the database, and it gives out an error where it should. What I want to do is make it so if there are multiple errors, it will point out that there are multiple and not just one. Right now my code still inserts into the database the correct lines of the text file and doesn't insert the wrong ones, but it only marks one error. Is there a way to put an if statement surrounding the catch clause or is there a more efficient way to identify multiple errors?? I want to do this for all the SQL exceptions such as wrong field, incorrect value type, etc.

```
        buttoninsert.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("create jdbc connection using properties file");

            Connection con = null;


            // use try becuase it tends to fail sometimes and we want error messages

            try {

                //load properties file we have created
                Properties prop = loadPropertiesFile();

                //declare vars and get the properties at the same time
                String driverClass = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.driver");
                String url = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.url");
                String username = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.username");
                String password = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.password");


                // have to instance driver
                Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance();

                // make connection object using the previous things as parameters
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

                //this if is to verify the connection
                if (con != null) {
                    System.out.println("connection created successfully using properties file");


                }

                else {
                    System.out.println(" unable to create connection");

                }


                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        "C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.txt"));

                ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                // Read line from file.
                while (true) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {

                        break;
                    }
                    // Split line on space.
                    String[] parts = line.split("");
                    //part in parts
                    for (String part : parts) {

                        //part is the element in this case each fix tag with value
                        array1.add(part);

                    }
                    String query = " insert into FRONTMC.HECHO (folio_hecho, folio_orden, emisora, serie,"
                            + "clave_sentido, titulos_hecho, precio, importe, liquidacion, contraparte, id_estatus, isin, contrato,"
                            + "secondary_exec_id, exec_id, F11_ClOrdID, fecha_recepcion, fecha_sentra)"
                                + " values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120),convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120))";

                              // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                              PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);


                              for(int counter =0; counter< array1.size();counter++){
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (1, array1.get(counter).substring(3));

                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (2, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }

                                  // change emisora and serie to 48 with bd
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("49=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (3, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }

                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("447=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (4, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("54=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (5, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("32=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (6, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("31=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (7, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("381=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (8, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("63=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (9, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("448=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (10, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("150=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (11, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("48=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (12, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 2).equals("1=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (13, array1.get(counter).substring(2));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("527=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (14, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("17=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (15, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("11=")){
                                      preparedStmt.setString (16, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                                      String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);

                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                        String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                                        String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                                        String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;


                                      preparedStmt.setString (17, newfecha1);
                                  }
                                  if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                                      String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);

                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                        String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                                        String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                                        String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;


                                      preparedStmt.setString (18, newfecha1);
                                  }

                              }

                              // execute the preparedstatement


                              preparedStmt.execute();
                              displaymsjfix.setText("exitoso");    
                }

                System.out.println(array1);


                reader.close();

                //creating the statement(should check to use prepared statement in the future

                // fecha recp y fecha sentra in query and for and ? and order



                          //notifies you that it was completed
                System.out.println("insert complete");
                // loop to check the digits ex. for() array.1get(counter).substring(0,3).equals("23=")

                //error messages
            }catch (SQLException eb) {
                eb.printStackTrace();
            } 

            //ERROR MESSAGE FECHA just get line number
            catch (Exception eb) {

                System.out.println("Error in date ");
            } finally {

                try {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get multiple errors thrown, as a method can only throw one exception and the SQL connector will just fail fast at the first one. I think what you're after is how to catch various errors and display these to the user?

You could parse the message string returned within the SQLException, and then display a more detailed error message?

Comment: Oh I see, thanks this really clears it up, I was really more asking if it was possible. But with multiple errors, does it still detect them and in the message string could I identify the various errors?

Comment: I could be wrong, but i'm pretty sure that if you try to execute an invalid SQL query the driver will just return with the first error it finds. So you won't get more than one source of error from the driver class, if you wanted that you'd probably have to write your own parser for the SQL query and then handle multiple error messages yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the query you will only get the most precedence error (first error it finds) in your SQLException, similar as the error you'd get if you execute the query as native SQL on the database itself (so not through the Java code, but through SQLDeveloper or similar SQL-tools).

In your case the best alternative I can give you is:

1. Manual validation before executing the query
2. **Don't use just `.setString` if the Database values are numeric, dates, etc.**

In your current code you insert all your values as Strings into the database. Usually you only want to use `.setString` for `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` values. If a database value is `NUMERIC`, I suggest to use `.setInteger` or `.setLong` (or others depending on the size of the NUMERIC). If all Java fields are only Strings, which seems to be the case judging by the many `substrings` you use, you can first convert those Strings to Integers in the Java code and then use `.setInteger` on the PreparedStatement.

It doesn't really answer your question, but at least you won't get incorrect value-type errors anymore.

The `convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120)` part of your query could just be `?` if you use `.setDate` instead of `.setString` (I think, not 100% sure, because I'm not sure what your input-data is, and what the query is that's being generated by the PreparedStatement. It is possible you'd still need to configure something so it converts to the correct database Date-format if it doesn't do this by default.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list with all errors occurred, you need to `try-catch` within your `while-loop`, not outside.

1. create a `List<String> errors`
2. parse the exception message and add it to the list.
3. At the end op the program, printout all errors.

Answer (score 0):

From your line "Right now my code still inserts into the database the correct lines of the text file and doesn't insert the wrong ones, but it only marks one error", I am assuming that you want to keep firing sqlqueries upto last line and collect all error messages that comes up.

You should not do that, this is a bad practice, but down the line in java I think there is a way.

```
List<String> exceptionList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(true)
{
   //Your code
    try
     {
        //sql statements and prepared statements
     }
     catch(SqlException e)
     {
            exceptionList.add(e.getMessage());
            continue;
     }
}
```